# Find the limit of the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2 y^2}{x^2 y^2 + (x-y)^2}$ whenever $x^2 y^2 + (x-y)^2 \not= 0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0) $

Tags: limits, scalar-fields

> Find the limit of the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2 y^2}{x^2 y^2 +
> > (x-y)^2}$ whenever $x^2 y^2 + (x-y)^2 \not= 0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0) $

I thought I can split this question into 4 limit question like 
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0^+, 0^+)} f(x,y)$$
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0^+, 0^-)} f(x,y)$$
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0^-, 0^+)} f(x,y)$$
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0^-, 0^-)} f(x,y)$$

Logically, this way of looking the question should not be a problem, but it is to a efficient way to do it, especially if f(x,y) is more complicated than the one in this question.

So, how can I solve this question  more efficiently ? and what is the correct solution ?

Answer (score 2):

The limit can be split into two cases.

$1.$ The limit is traversed along the line $x=y$

$2.$ The limit is not traversed along the line $x=y$

Case $1$: Substitution leads to direct cancellation, and the limit in that case is $1$.

Case $2$: By setting $y=kx$ where $k \neq 1$, the limit is $0$.

Conclusion: The limit does not exist.

Comment: Can we use this method for any f(x,y) ?

Comment: No, this does not generalise to arbitrary functions.

Comment: @Leth We can always try to search for two paths, as long as you are only trying to show that the limit does ***not*** exist. If any two paths result in different values we determine the limit does not exist. Actually evaluating an existing limit is a completely different problem, and can often involve resorting to $\epsilon - \delta$ arguments

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen but using the formal definition of limit wouldn't be more complicated ?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I mean in this case yes I can prove it with the formal definition almost easily, but what if I face with a more complicated function ?

Comment: @JackLam By the way, in case 2, the limit becomes $\frac{0}{0}$, which goes to 0 if we use the l'hospital's rule.